# When service through external host name returns wsdl html instead of the expected response envelope

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis, wsdl

I have an IIS-hosted, WCF web service deployed on a UAT web server. In IIS, I have site bindings on this same web service--one for internal access (Ex: uat-nodotsinternalonly) and one for external access (Ex: mysvc.uat.mydomain.com).

When I use SoapUI to test against the internal host name (http://uat-nodotsinternalonly/MyService.svc), it calls the service and returns the response envelope as expected.

When I use SoapUI to test against the external host name (https://mysvc.uat.mydomain.com/MyService.svc), it calls the service and returns the WSDL HTML as would be seen in the web browser instead of the response envelope as expected.

We need to expose past our firewall for testing with a vendor. Our external client can browse to our web service using the external host name and receive the WSDL back in their web browser, but when they call it, it fails with a 302 error.

I’m far from an expert on security, but I believe our firewall is handling the security then forwarding over http to the UAT server. The redirect and variations seem as though there’s something to change in how DNS is managed or settings in IIS. Does anyone have suggestions as to how to narrow it down so that the call to the external service will work?

Answer (score 2):

We too had a WCF service that in SoapUI was returning the WSDL HTML instead of the expected response when invoking a method.  This was an SSL-enabled service, and the solution in our case was to edit the endpoint URL *after* creating the request so that it used https instead of http.  This is because we found that for some reason it defaults to http even when you initially specify https when creating the request.  Here's how to edit the endpoint URL in SoapUI:

1. In the request window, click the drop-down arrow on the URL.
2. Select [edit current..]

Change http to https, and then try your request again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the client getting a 302 error was because the client was not sending a SOAP request envelope to our web service. The client was just sending XML.